Requesting a reference for the fact that discriminant is homogeneous
I request a reference for the fact that the discriminants are homogeneous and its coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$. More precisely, I want a reference for the following fact:

The discriminant of the polynomial $f = x^{n} + a_{1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1} x + a_{n}\in \left(\mathbb{Z}\left[a_{1},\cdots,a_{n}\right]\right)\left[x\right]$ has integral coefficients and is a homogeneous polynomial of $a_{i}$'s of weight $n\left(n-1\right)$ when we assign the weight such that $\operatorname{wt}\left(a_{i}\right) = i$.

I want a source that I can refer like a book but not a website.
